# Angular Array.push is pushing only last object in the array when the mat-checkbox is checked

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two components **item-list** and **item** . The item-list component display a list of items with checkboxes. I have been trying to push the items to a new Array when checked in the checkbox, but the Array holds only the last item when logged.

Below is the code I tried,

**item-list.component.html**

```
<div>
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <input matInput placeholder="Add a Task" (keyup.enter)="addTask()"autocomplete="off"[formControl]="nameControl"/>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>

<app-item
  [value]="value"
  *ngFor="let value of data; index as index"
  >
</app-item>
```

**item.component.html**

```
<div class="listContainer">
  <div class="checkContainer">
  <mat-checkbox color="secondary" [(ngModel)]="IsChecked" (change)="onChange($event)"> 
  </mat-checkbox>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="displayTask">
 <div class="displayvalue" [ngClass]="{ 'line-through': value.task }">
  {{ value.task | uppercase }}
 </div>
</div>
```

**item.component.Ts**

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-item',
  templateUrl: './item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./item.component.scss'],
})

export class ItemComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  value: any;

  IsChecked: boolean;
  public ArrayChecked: any[] = [];

  constructor() {
    this.IsChecked = false;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  onChange($event: any) {
     if ($event.checked) {
       this.ArrayChecked.push(this.value.task);

       console.log('the task is added', this.ArrayChecked);
     } 
     else console.log('the task is removed');
  }
  }
```

In the above code for component **item**, I tried pushing the items to a new array 'ArrayChecked' inside the onChange(), but when I log the result, the array holds only the last item that I checked. I would like to get the list of all items that were checked in the checkboxes.

Can someone help me fix my code , so all the checked items are inside 'ArrayChecked[]'. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `ArrayChecked` is initialized in every `item` component, which means that each component is only going to push values to its own `ArrayChecked` variable. Therefore, only the value of the last checked checkbox is logged.

This can be fixed by initializing `ArrayChecked` in the `item-list` component instead of the `item` component. Then, the `item` component should fire an event when its checkbox's value changes with the item's task. You can then listen to this event in `item-list` and push the task to `ArrayChecked`.

**item.component.ts**

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-item',
  templateUrl: './item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./item.component.scss'],
})

export class ItemComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  value: any;

  // Emitted when the task is checked
  @Output()
  checkTask = new EventEmitter<any>;

  IsChecked: boolean;

  constructor() {
    this.IsChecked = false;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  onChange($event: any) {
     if ($event.checked) {
       // We now emit the checkTask event instead of directly pushing it to the array
       this.checkTask.emit(this.value.task);

       console.log('the task is added', this.ArrayChecked);
     } 
     else console.log('the task is removed');
  }
}
```

**item-list.component.html**

```
<app-item
  [value]="value"
  (checkTask)="addCheckedTask($event)"
  *ngFor="let value of data; index as index"
  >
</app-item>
```

**item-list.component.ts**

```
addCheckedTask($event: any): void {
  this.ArrayChecked.push($event);
}
```